# How to have an MX Entry set only for one email

Tags: email, mx-record

So I'm using cPANEL, and I have a problem with my email. I recently took the hosting of a website and i try to make the emails work the same way as they use too.

One of the users has a gMail account : user@domain.com and receive her email on her gmail. It works if I set an MX Entry for ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM priority 1

But the other users are using POP3 to connect to the mail server, so I defined: domain.com priority 0.

Unfortunately, when I do this, the person on gMail doesn't receive her email any more. Her email address doesn't exist on my server.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MX is per domain, and can't be per-user. So all the mail for domain.com will arrive to (one of) the SMTP servers you define in MX.

Then you can setup mail forwarding to deliver mail to different external accounts.

Alternatively you can deliver all mail to POP3 mailboxes, and gmail user can setup POP download in gmail settings to pull mail from POP3 box.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you cannot have separate MX records for individual users.  MX records are authoritative for the entire domain - that is to say, MX records work for domain.com only - they're not granular by user.

Your best bet is to set the MX records to point to one server (I recommend the POP server in this instance), and then have the POP server forward mail for the one Gmail account to Gmail.